# how to ask recalculate the size of UITableView(TTTableView) from inside a UITableViewCell(TTTableViewCell)

Tags: iphone, resize, three20, tableview, uitableview

My tableview cells (TTTAbleViewCells) cells contain images that are loaded from the internet aynchronously.When the image is loaded the the table view cell gets a callback from the TTImageView object.

Question is at the point of the callback how can i ask the parent TTTableView to change the height of the cells and resize accordingly.

It seems like the call to heightForRowAtIndexPath is only at the beginning of tableview drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I will answer my own question here.

```
- (void)imageView:(TTImageView*)imageView didLoadImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell:self];
    if(indexPath!=nil)
    {   
        NSArray* path = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
        [(UITableView*)[self superview] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:path withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  I'd recommend resizing your images to fit into your cells, rather than vice-versa

Comment: It is possible Andrew.The facebook for iphone app does this successfully.

Comment: in fact I have a solution myself but it is very hackish.
The TTTableView cell can set the delegate of the TTImageView to the TTableView itself.When the TTTableView gets a callback from the imageView it determines from [[imageView superView] superView] the cell and finds out the indexpath of the cell by comparing it to all the cells.After it has found the indexpath of the cell it calls 

[self reloadCellAtIndexPath:

It can work but like I said it is very hackish.

Comment: Ah what I don't think is possible is setting the height from the cell itself.  but if you've got it working you should be all set? :)

Comment: well i havent really got it working yet..:)..i was looking for a more elegant solution...but i guess i will go ahead and try this one!